# Searching through list

Tags: list, haskell, integer, boolean

I've been trying to define a function which, given a list of Integers and an Integer n, returns a Boolean indicating whether n occurs exactly once in the list.

I have this, but it is not working and I cannot figure it out

```
once :: [a] -> (a -> Bool) -> Bool 
filter _ [] = []  
filter p (x:xs)   
    | p x       = x : filter p xs  
    | otherwise = filter p xs 

An example of what I want would be:
Main>  once [2,3,2,4] 2
False
Main> once [1..100] 2
True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
once :: (Eq a) => [a] -> a -> Bool
once xs x = (== 1) $ length $ filter (== x) xs
```

Comment: Thanks for this, any idea how to deal with lists that are infinite?

Comment: John, you'll need to match on the list for its length, rather than taking the length, as as in the answer below.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to handle infinite lists in the general case. How would any deterministic program know to stop looking for `1` in `repeat 2`?

Comment: You could rework it to handle the case where more than one occurrence in an infinite list returns false, but that seems kind of pointless because you can never return true, and you can't even return false in the case where there are no occurrences.

Answer (score 6):

As I thought my former solution was ugly, I asked in [another forum](http://www.jammni.de/php/forum.php?forum=6&posting=3063&offset=last) and got this as answer:

```
once :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
once x = (== [x]) . filter (== x)
```

I think you can't write that function much nicer, and in contrast to the accepted answer it's lazy.

Comment: +1 for terminating on a second occurrence of x instead of walking the whole list (which `length` does).

Comment: *1, but it is only lazier if there is indeed a 2nd x and if it's not the last element. To be honest, he who applies this function must assume that the whole list will be evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can filter the list, then see how many elements are in the resulting filter, right?

To get you started:

```
 > filter (== 2) [1,2,3,4,5]
 [2]

 > filter (== 2) [1,2,3,4,5,2,2]
 [2,2,2]
```

And to fold your list down to a Bool value, here, an example where we test if a list has three elements, returning a Bool:

```
 > isThree (a:b:c:[]) = True
 > isThree _          = False
```

So it is just a short matter of composing such functions:

```
 > isThree . filter (==2)
```

or your variant (e.g. matching for lists of length 1).

Comment: I know that already but I just dont know how to output to a boolean instead of listing the contents that match.

Comment: Compare the length of the list against 1?

Comment: Once :: [a] -> a -> Bool
filter (k) [a]
If 1<a true
otherwise False

That sort of thing?

Comment: @John  Use the `length` function and don't compare the value of an element, `a` in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version:

```
once x = not . (\xs -> null xs || x `elem` tail xs) . dropWhile (/= x)

--lambda hater version
import Control.Applicative
once x = not . ((||) <$> null <*> (elem x).tail) . dropWhile (/= x)
```

Of course it can't deal with infinite lists that contain zero or one x, but at least it terminates in case of more than one occurrence of x.