# How to deal with duplicate elements in the list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, duplicates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Searching through list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600706/searching-through-list)

I need to write a function 'once' which, given a list of Integers and an Integer n, returns a Boolean indicating whether n occurs exactly once in the list. E.g.

```
Main>  once [2,3,2,4] 2
False
Main> once [1..100] 2
True
```

And here is my current code:

```
once :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool
once x [] = False
once x (y:ys) = (x==y) || (once x ys)
```

It checks only whether x is part of the list, but it cannot tell x appeared more than once in the list and therefore return false.
Need help with this, thanks!

Comment: I bet for two students following the same course :D

Comment: I hope Prof van Deemter doesn't decide to set another assessment because your to stupid and lazy to, not only do the assessment yourself but to even change the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possibilities doing that. If you know that the list is finite, you could say:

```
once x xs = length (filter (==x) xs) == 1
```

(If it's not finite, there is no solution.)

By the way, you had it almost in your solution, you just replace

```
|| (once x ys)
```

with

```
&& (x `notElem` ys)
```

Comment: what if it s an infinite set, thanks...

Comment: It might take a while if it is infinite :)

Comment: This is an exact duplicate, even down to the follow up question, of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600706/searching-through-list ...

Comment: With an infinite list, an algorithm could only terminate if the second x is found. Therefore, such a function could only return False in some case, but wouuld run forever when the list contained no or 1 x. A statistician could argue that the possibility that an infinite list contains at least 2 times the same value (from a finite domain) is high. Even in the case (once x (repeat (x+1))) the computer could produce s random result due to hardware error every other billion years. If you don't mind waiting that long --- still you would only ever get False as result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- write a function `once`, that scans the list until it finds the element for the first time or the end of the list. In the latter case it returns `False`, else it calls `once'`on the rest of the list and returns the result.
- `once'` does essentially the same as `once`, but returns `False`, if the element is found and `True`, if not.